# Clearing MDC when HTTP response is sent by Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, mdc

I'm building a Java back-end using Spring with Jersey, where I want to send a multipart response to the client.

I have a GET call that looks something like this:

```
@Path("/status/{requestID}")
@GET
public Response getStatus(@PathParam("requestID") String requestId) {
    MDC.put("myRequestID", requestId);
    // Do some processing
    return response;
}
```

I use MDC to add request ID and other information that I need in my logs. Now the response that I create is Multipart, and since Jersey internally converts this Multipart response to HTTP response, during this processing I have certain callbacks which logs messages and I want the MDC to be populated at that time, with whatever was put in my `getStatus` call.

Now, usually I would call `MDC.clear()` before returning status in my `getStatus` call. But, now that I want to wait for Jersey to complete processing, I cannot do that.

Is there any callback that Jersey provides once the HTTP response processing is complete, where I can do this cleanup?

Comment: Have you thought about using a Filter to populate (and clear) the MDC instead of doing it in every Request Handler mehtod? - Or it this not possible because the mdc paramter is not the same for all requests?

Comment: @Ralph Yes, these parameters are not same for all requests.

Comment: One workarround is to have a global request interceptor / filter that add and clear MDC parameter (lets call it "request-number") with an unique id. -- Then all log statments to within the exection of this request can be grouped by this MDC-parameter. - pro very easy, con - it is just an artificial ID without any meaning, you will still need to search for the log statement that write your specific request ID and the one that log some other event.